# How to search a CLSID in windows component services?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, security

I get this error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070520): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070520 A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Some one gave me a hint to find the CLSID in the Component Services and give it permission. But how can I find the CLSID there? there are just names.

Comment: You can look up the name of the CLSID in Regedit, then set permissions in Component Services.

Comment: yes, now I see it in regedit, but the friendly name in component services doesn't exist. now what should I do?

Comment: OK: so your friend's hint to "give it permission in Component Services" didn't pan out.  It was a good guess - but it sounds like that's not the problem.  SUGGESTION: troubleshoot  `80070520 A specified logon session does not exist`.  There are many possible reasons.  For example: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10-mso_o365b/error-code-80070520-a-specified-logon-session-does/655beadf-2948-43d4-b50f-e338815615fb